# How to set table default autovacuum_analyze_threshold

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Team,
We have updated aggressive analyze factor from table level like below.
Options: autovacuum_analyze_threshold=400

Now we would like to rollback with default value. can anyone suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `reset` option of the [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) statement for that:

```
alter table the_table
  reset (autovacuum_analyze_threshold);
```